# What is the right query to Empty Table in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code about trying to attempt to empty my table, and it doesn't work every time I use the button named `delete`. Does anyone know what is the right approach for this query? Please help, thanks in advance.

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $EmptyQuery = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE `tblresult`", $connect);
};

  <form id="NewEvaluation" method=post action=setnewevaluation.php onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to set a new evaluation? this will empty all the table for results,evaluate,answers and finalresults.');">
 <input type="image" name='delete' id=confirm src="Confirmdean.jpg"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: TRUNCATE is the correct approach

Comment: I know, but my code does not seem to work.

Comment: well you say " doesnt work everytime " so it works some time? so whats the difference? its hard to diagnose this

Comment: no, it doesn't work at some time, this query really doesn't work unless I straight up go to tblresult - operation - then click "TRUNCATE table"

Comment: instead of an image input, try a `<input type='submit' name='delete' value='DELETE'>` instead. and check for errors on the query as I posted in that answer below to you. we also don't know whether or not you're using PHP tags or not around all that code of yours.

Comment: gone from works some times to not at all, if you can't actually describe the problem .. do you even have a db connection?

Comment: @Dagon it's their `<input type="image" name='delete' id=confirm src="Confirmdean.jpg"/>` that does *nothing*. Those don't process POSTs. Had my doubts at first, but then remembered that they don't process them. Just to be 100% sure, I tested it first.

Comment: @Fred-ii- stop being right all the time, it makes me look bad ;-)

Comment: @Dagon I'm only right when I'm right bro ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is here:

```
<input type="image" name='delete' id=confirm src="Confirmdean.jpg"/>
```

An image type as a submit will not process POST directives.

You need to use an actual submit type input.

```
<input type='submit' name='delete' value='DELETE'>
```

or as a button using a submit type:

```
<button type='submit' name='delete'>DELETE</button>
```

That's why your code isn't "firing up" anything inside that conditional statement and check for errors against your query also, something I said in comments twice already.

```
$EmptyQuery = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE `tblresult`", $connect) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone, it works fine now. the problem was is that I used image input not the regular input type submit button. Thanks.

```
 if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $EmptyQuery = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE `tblresult`", $connect) or die(mysql_error());
    $EmptyQuery1 = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE `tblfinalresult`", $connect) or die(mysql_error());
    $EmptyQuery2 = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE `tblevaluate`", $connect) or die(mysql_error());
    $EmptyQuery3 = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE `tblanswer`", $connect) or die(mysql_error());
    };

<form id="NewEvaluation" method=post action="" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to set a new evaluation? this will empty all the table for results,evaluate,answers and finalresults.');">
<input type='submit' name='delete' value='DELETE'>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you receive any error messages when it does not work? How often does the command not work? The code looks correct with out seeing the other components. Maybe you could try writing the the code a little different and see if it makes a difference.

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $query = "TRUNCATE TABLE table_name";
    $EmptyQuery = mysql_query($query,$connect);
};
```

I agree with Dagon, TRUNCATE is the right approach for emptying a table.

Comment: It doesn't really work at all. and no error messages is being shown when I run the system.

Comment: *"and no error messages"* - `$EmptyQuery = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE \`tblresult\`", $connect) or die(mysql_error());` and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php @ChristianQuirante